# Yjw to replace and then search with sed and find

Tags: linux, sed, find

I'm making a bash script which would call like

```
script.sh 172.16.1.1
```

trying to replace . and search files to delete them but it won't happen

```
echo $1 | find -name '*.`sed 's/\.*//g'`' -printf "%f\n" -delete
```

files look like

```
eth0-2:120.1721611  eth1-2:120.1721611
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what you are asking. What is your input and expected output?

Comment: Those files are in current directory or not.

Comment: And what you are trying to do with those files. I cant understand why you are echoing and then trying to pipe the output to find command can you ealborate the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command inside that script. 
I think this may help you for your requirement.

$ find -name "*`echo "$1" | sed 's/\.*//g'`" -printf "%f\n" -delete

I am passing the name only for the particular field, If you passed for whole command it produce the different result.

The given command is searched from current directory to end.

If you need to search from root or home use `/` or `~` in find command like

$ find ~ -name "*`echo "$1" | sed 's/\.*//g'`" -printf "%f\n" -delete